# How to use the Spanish Wordnet in NLTK?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I just downloaded a Spanish Wordnet from the project  [GRIAL](http://grial.uab.es/sensem), the format is XML. How can I use it in Python NLTK?

Besides that, in the same page you can download a tagged corpus in Spanish. How can I incorporate it as well?

Comment: why not just use NLTK's built-in Spanish functionality?

Comment: @JamesTobin the problem with the built-in is that it is very deep, and is not very precise. Do you have any idea of how integrate?

Comment: well, my Spanish is limited, so trying to navigate the website you listed was tough for me. but considering you have the xml I'm sure you could do something with NLTKs Corpus reader. they can read in an XML file, using http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.corpus.reader.xmldocs-module.html probably

Comment: Linkrot has set in for this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use XMLCorpusReader to load XML data as corpus

Here's the code to do that

```
from nltk.corpus.reader import XMLCorpusReader
reader = XMLCorpusReader(dir, file)
```

A fully working example which uses XMLCorpusReader is given [here](http://sujitpal.blogspot.in/2013/04/language-model-to-detect-medical.html)