# How to load plwordnet (Słowosieć) 3.0 into NLTK

Tags: nltk, wordnet

PlWordNet version 3.0 comes with two `.xml` files. First file is `plwordnet-3.0.xml` (which is in `Princeton WordNet format`) and second file is `plwordnet-3.0-visdisc.xml` (which is in `VizDic format`). The *readme* file of this projects seems to be somehow obscure, because suggested way of loading the data into NLTK doesn't work. The PlWordNet is available for download from the official [project site](http://nlp.pwr.wroc.pl/plwordnet/download/?lang=eng).

I'm trying to load this wordnet into NLTK, so I can iterate over synsets. I already tried two ways, but both of them don't work.

a) *copying the xml files* into `(...)\nltk_data\corpora\omw\pol` and `(...)\nltk_data\corpora\wordnet`. Code to test results:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
wn.synsets('Politechnika')
```

unfortunately returns empty list

b) *using XMLCorpusReader* from the nltk package (as described in [How to use the Spanish Wordnet in NLTK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615741/how-to-use-the-spanish-wordnet-in-nltk)) to load the xml file. Code to test:

```
from nltk.corpus.reader import XMLCorpusReader
reader = XMLCorpusReader(dir, 'plwordnet-3.0.xml')
```

but when I run the `reader.words()`, it returns only a list of ids (unicode objects, representing numbers only). Moreover I don't see a method for getting relations between synsets.

Anyone used the Princeton Wordnet 3.1 or PlWordNet (Słowosieć) 3.0 before?

I managed to use python's `xml.etree` to manually get list of synsets and their descriptions, but I don't understand how to get **relations** between them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PlWordNet 3.0 is not supported in NLTK anymore.

I'll write my own parser.

Comment: did you write it? any hints?

Comment: @oski86 - if you have written it, could you please share the link to your repository (e.g. GitHub)?